# Time start to specific time end from multiple locations

Tags: excel, date, time, subtraction

I am attempting  in creating an Excell page that determines the START time from multiple locations, from different time distnances to a single point.

Lets say that i have 15 start points from varying locations trying to reach a single destination. I am trying to set the arrival time as the end point and work backwords by using the destination time it takes. For instance, i want to coordinate a multiutude of units to converge at 11pm at night. I know that the first unit takes 5h30m, and the second takes 2h 45m to reach the same point at the same time. I would have to calcuate 11pm -5h30m = 5:30pm march srart for unit one, and 11pm-2h45m = 8:15pm for unit 2.

I have tried the subraction using the [h]:mm military script with subraction of the time to desitnation. All that has resulted is the difference between.   ie 23:00 - 13:00 = 10:00 .  But if the destinatiin time is 08:30 - 1300 all i get is #######.  Where the first time is convergeance time and the 2nd time is march time.

I was able to get it to work if the comon convergeance time did not cause the march time to be before 00:01. And thats the crux , i cant seam to get it to work for a start time before midnight.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Use date and time, and not just times. You would probably also get an 'issue' around a daylight saving cusps so best to work in gmt through-out and convert from/to day-light-saving time (user time) for entry and display.

Comment: I would like to say that i wish it was more complicated then the answer, BUT i am not. I tried to make it harder then what it was, looking back the answer was so simple. Thank you very much.

Comment: @ChuckStevens If you're happy with the solution proposed - please accept the answer by ticking it, this will mark the question solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use times only then try using `MOD` function, e.g. with A2 = 23:00 and B2 = 2:45 you can use

`=MOD(A2-B2,1)`

and that will give you 20:15

......but it also works with A2 = 08:30 and B2 = 13:00....the same formula will give you 19:30